# Fatal error: Class 'Dwoo' not found inapplication/libraries/MY_Parser.php on line 57

Tags: codeigniter, template-engine, dwoo

Ok, I am having a class not found problem with Codeigniter (latest edition) and Dwoo while working with Phil Sturgeon's templating system.  I have followed PHil's instructions found [here](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/codeigniter-dwoo). But when I run my application, I keep getting a Class 'Dwoo' not found in Phil's MY_Parser library on line 57. Did I miss something common in the installation?  I can get his template system to work just fine without the Dwoo addition.

Is there anything that I am gaining by using Dwoo with Phil's templating system, besides the shortened template tag within views and templates??

Tony

Answer (score 0):

This is really too late to reply but this might help others stuck at the same problem as I was :P

I know you might have fixed this, anyway you were missing:

```
include(APPPATH.'libraries/dwoo/dwooAutoload.php');
```

And the benefits of using Dwoo with Phil's templating system depends on your requirements.